# How To Use A Proxy Pass For All Incoming API Request

Tags: nginx, server, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am setting up a server to host my website using nginx but i am having trouble with my backend working. Currently I only use Restful APIs and am trying to use proxypasses within nginx to hit my backend, but do I have to add a location for every api endpoint. For example my backend server is ran from pm2 on localhost:5000, all of my endpoints entail http://myip/api/(my-endpoint), if I setup the nginx to look like this:

```
location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /api {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/api;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
```

it still doesnt work. What is the best way to go about setting up nginx to handle all requests from my front end to backend? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you don't use a slash `/` at the end of the proxy URL, it adds `/api` to the later `proxy_pass` so you eventually get `http://localhost:5000/api/api`.

Try using a slash by the end of the root URL:

```
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
    }
```